# Yiistrap Form Submission

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am having trouble getting Yiistrap to work with form submissions. I am currently able to successfully save a form using standard Yii syntax like this:

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Deal_Name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'Deal_Name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'Deal_Name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Owner'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'Owner'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'Owner'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Division'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'Division'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'Division'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

However when I want to do a Yiistrap form I cannot get it to save properly, most likely I am missing the proper parameters to send the form correctly. Below is my Yiistrap code:

```
<?php echo TbHtml::beginFormTb(TbHtml::FORM_LAYOUT_HORIZONTAL)
); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::textFieldControlGroup('Land_Deal', '',
        array('label' => 'Land Deal', 'placeholder' => 'Land Deal'
    )); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::textFieldControlGroup('Owner', '',
        array('label' => 'Responible Party', 'placeholder' => 'Responsible Party'
    )); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::textFieldControlGroup('Division', '',
        array('label' => 'Division', 'placeholder' => 'Division'
    )); ?>
    <?php echo TbHTML::submitButton('Save'
    ); ?>
<?php echo TbHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

Could you guys give me some insight as to what I am missing?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code contains syntax error. Replace by this line and check-- <?php echo TbHtml::beginFormTb(TbHtml::FORM_LAYOUT_HORIZONTAL); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the YiiStrap widget instead of the form and it worked perfectly.